# Expressing Riemann sums as integrals

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

$$L_2=\lim_{n→∞}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(k-\cos^2(k))^4}{n^5}.$$
My teacher said that when brackets at the numarator is expanded the limit of sum except $\dfrac{k^4}{n^5}$ equals $0$, so the Riemann sum becomes $\lim\limits_{n→∞}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^4}{n^5}$. I don't understand this point. Please explain this point. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{j} \leq \int_1^{n} x^{j} dx =\frac {n^{j+1} -1} {j+1}$ and $\frac {n^{j+1} -1} {n^{5}} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ if $j <4$. Hence, when you expand $(k-\cos^{2}(k))^{4}$ all terms except $k^{4}$ give limit $0$. [Note that $\cos^{2} k \leq 1$].

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\frac{(k-\cos^2 k)^4}{n^5}=\sum \left(\frac{k^4-4k^3\cos ^2\left(k\right)+6k^2\cos ^4\left(k\right)-4k\cos ^6\left(k\right)+\cos ^8\left(k\right)}{n^5}\right)$$Every term is involving $\cos k$ except the term $k^4$. Applying summation and use algebra of limits together with the fact $\cos k$ is bounded by $1$ to get your result

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\left(k-\cos^2(k)\right)^4}{n^5}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac{k^4}{n^5}+O\!\left(\frac{k^3}{n^5}\right)\right]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^4}{n^4}\frac1n+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\right]\\
&=\int_0^1x^4\,\mathrm{d}x+0\\[6pt]
&=\frac15
\end{align}
$$